# Subsection header text overlaps with Page header text

Tags: formatting

I am using the below code for a document, but I am running into an error whereby the page header (code below)

```
\rhead{\large\centering{\textit{title at top of all pages}}}
```

overlaps with headings for subsections (code below)

```
\subsection{subsection}
    \label{text}
```

How can I make the page header appear only on the first page, (which would hopefully solve the problem), or stop subsection headings from overlapping with the page header on later pages

Main document code below

```
     \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[tmargin=1.25in,bmargin=1.25in,lmargin=1.5in,rmargin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}               % Times Roman
\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{helvet} % Helvetica
\usepackage{sectsty}             
\sectionfont{\large\sffamily}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathptmx}            %used to make Title larger

%% Packages used for Algorithms
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
%% Packages used for referencing
\usepackage[nosectionbib,numberedbib]{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\refname{REFERENCES}}


\begin{document}
\raggedright

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rhead{\large\centering{\textit{top page header}}}
\rfoot{Copyright $\textcopyright$ 2018}
\cfoot{}
\sffamily
\noindent\rule{14cm}{1pt}


\begin{center}


\Huge\bfseries\sffamily {\fontsize{35}{60}\selectfont Title}
%\par
\vspace{5mm}
\end{center}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\noindent\rule{14cm}{1pt}
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont

\begin{flushleft}
\vspace{7mm}
\par
\large{\textbf{authors}}
\vspace{5mm}
\par
\large{\textit{text}}
\par
%\vspace{5mm}
\section*{ABSTRACT}

text
\vspace{5mm}
\par 
\textit{Keyword:  text.} 
\par  
\vspace{5mm}
\noindent\rule{14cm}{1pt}
\vspace{5mm}
\par


\section{INTRODUCTION}
\label{introduction}
\vspace{-3mm}

text
\par
\vspace{2mm}

text
\par
\vspace{2mm}
text

\begin{enumerate}
\item text;
\item text;
\item text. 
\end{enumerate}


\vspace{2mm}
\par

\section{RELATED WORK}
\label{relatedwork}
\vspace{-3mm}

text
\vspace{5mm}
\par

\subsection{text}
\label{text}

text

\subsection{text}
\label{text}

text

\subsection{text}
\label{text}

text

\vspace{2mm}
\par


\section{text}
\label{text}
%\vspace{-3mm}

text

%\vspace{7mm}
%\par

\subsection{text}
\label{text}

%\vspace{5mm}
%\par
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{IMG/pic.pdf}
    \caption{txt}
    \label{text}
\end{figure}




text

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Example Algorithm}\label{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State \text{dataProcessing (dataset)} 
        \State $\textit{unitToDrop} \gets \text{25\%}$
        \State \text{text}
        \State \text{text}
        \Repeat
        \State \text{/*text*/}
        \For{$i\gets 1, rows$}
        \State $\text{text}$ 
        \State $\text{text}$ 
        \State $\text{text}$ 
        \State \text{text}
        \State $\text{text}$
        \EndFor
        \Until {text}
        \State \text{text}
        \Repeat
        \State \text{text}
        \For{$i\gets 1, rows$}
        \State $\text{text}$ 
        \State $\text{v}$ 
        \EndFor
        \Until {text}
        \State \textbf{Return}  \text{text, text}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}



\subsection{text}
\label{text}
\vspace{-3mm}
text
\vspace{5mm}
\par


\subsubsection{text}
\vspace{-3mm}
text
\vspace{5mm}
\par

\subsubsection{text}
\vspace{-3mm}
text
\vspace{5mm}
\par

\subsection{text}
\label{text}
\vspace{1mm}


text

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Example Algorithm}\label{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State \text{dataProcessing (dataset)} 
        \State $\textit{unitToDrop} \gets \text{25\%}$
        \State \text{text}
        \State \text{text}
        \Repeat
        \State \text{/*text*/}
        \For{$i\gets 1, rows$}
        \State $\text{text}$ 
        \State $\text{text}$ 
        \State $\text{text}$ 
        \State \text{text}
        \State $\text{text}$
        \EndFor
        \Until {text}
        \State \text{text}
        \Repeat
        \State \text{text}
        \For{$i\gets 1, rows$}
        \State $\text{text}$ 
        \State $\text{v}$ 
        \EndFor
        \Until {text}
        \State \textbf{Return}  \text{text, text}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

text



\vspace{5mm}
\par


\subsubsection{text}
\vspace{-3mm}
text
\vspace{5mm}
\par

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Example Algorithm}\label{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \State \text{dataProcessing (dataset)} 
        \State $\textit{unitToDrop} \gets \text{25\%}$
        \State \text{text}
        \State \text{text}
        \Repeat
        \State \text{/*text*/}
        \For{$i\gets 1, rows$}
        \State $\text{text}$ 
        \State $\text{text}$ 
        \State $\text{text}$ 
        \State \text{text}
        \State $\text{text}$
        \EndFor
        \Until {text}
        \State \text{text}
        \Repeat
        \State \text{text}
        \For{$i\gets 1, rows$}
        \State $\text{text}$ 
        \State $\text{v}$ 
        \EndFor
        \Until {text}
        \State \textbf{Return}  \text{text, text}
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\subsubsection{text}
\vspace{-3mm}
text
\vspace{5mm}
\par

\begin{table*}[h!]
    \fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
    \centering
    \caption{text}
    \label{text}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{4.2cm}|p{1.0cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{2.2cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
        \hline

    \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}text\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}text\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}text\end{tabular}} & 
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}text\end{tabular}}
  \\  \hline
        text & text   & 208418  & 99.998992 & 0.000809  \\ \hline
        text & 391002    & 210540    & 98.582144 & 0.125630   \\ \hline
        text & 411384 & 221515 & 93.765198 & 0.858700   \\ \hline
        text & 391622 & 210874 & 98.488289 & 0.116453  \\ \hline
        text & 419887   & 226094 & 91.951002 & 0.841303  \\ \hline
        text & 395564    & 212996 &  97.521033 & 0.115293  \\ \hline
        text & 468534 & 252289 & 92.243513 & 0.161890  \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}



\begin{figure}[h!]%
    \centering
    \subfloat[text]{{\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{IMG/text.pdf} }}%
    \qquad
    \subfloat[text]{{\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{IMG/text.pdf} }}%
    \caption{text}%
    \label{usa_canada}%
\end{figure}


blh blah blah




\section{text}
\label{text}
\vspace{-3mm}
text
\vspace{7mm}
\par




\section{text}
\label{text}
\vspace{-3mm}
text
\vspace{7mm}
\par

\section{text}
\label{text}
\vspace{-3mm}
text
\vspace{7mm}
\par








\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{sa.bib}

%\vspace{7mm}
%\par
\section*{text}
\label{key}
\vspace{-7mm}
\par
\noindent\rule{14cm}{1pt}
\vspace{-3mm}
\par
text
\vspace{7mm}
\par

%\vspace{7mm}
%\par
\section*{text}
\label{bio}
\vspace{-7mm}
\par
\noindent\rule{14cm}{1pt}
\vspace{-3mm}
\par
\textbf{text} 

text

\vspace{7mm}
\par

\textbf{text} 

text


\vspace{7mm}
\par


%\vspace{7mm}
%\par
\section*{text}
\label{text}
\vspace{-7mm}
\par
\noindent\rule{14cm}{1pt}
\vspace{-3mm}
\par
\textbf{text}: text

\vspace{7mm}
\par

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the markup in the document is very strange (why all the vspaces???) but it does not appear to be an example of the problem you ask about. There is only one subsection and its title comes towards the bottom of page 1 and does not overlap the page head.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes the document is a little strange (it wasn't me who created it but need to use it). In my full document I have several subsections but I have only put one here as a MWE

Comment: the example has to be an example of the problem, otherwise there is no point in posting it!!!  So far all we know is that some document that you have not shown has some overprinting. If like the document that is here it is full of negative vspaces then overprinting is not that surprising but without seeing any example how can anyone offer any help?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand your point but I am normally told to putup a MWE rather than a full document ? I will update question with all subsections

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have uploaded a complete document minus the body text, as requested thanks

Comment: yes you should post a MWE not the full original document but the E in MWE means it should be _an example of the problem_ posting code that does not show the problem is not useful.  The edited version is not a MWE as it fails with `! Package pdftex.def Error: File \`IMG/text.pdf' not found:` but it is better as it does show that the log warns of your problem and how to correct it:  `Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 14.0pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.`

Comment: the example also is still not an example of the problem as stated, it does not show any subsection overprinting the page header

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure how to show the problem without posting the whole document. The problem arises when the body of text is entered not in the blank document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle when I convert the subsections to sections I do not get a problem. When I have one subsection in a section it seems to be ok. As soon as I add more than one subsection under a section it overlaps

Comment: If you want someone to debug an overlapping heading _post an example of that_ but if you have the warning from fancyhdr first do what it says and add `\setlength\headheight{14pt}` to your preamble

Comment: to make a MWE you can add dummy text eg if your original text has a 5 line paragraph add `a\\b\\c\\d\\e`  and any other dummy text, and make sure it shows the problem, replace images (which are not needed to show the problem by `\rule{1cm}{6cm}` or whatever size is needed to take the same space as the image